# How to integrate cordova-plugin-firebase-crash plugin with ionic app

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-crash-reporting

I am implementing crash report for my ionic app using firebase cordova plugin

I am install following plugin
-> https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-crash

But i don't know how crash report display in our google firebase account and how to connect those account and our ionic app

I have also create app in firebase account and export -> google-services.json file, How to connect .json file and our cordova plugin?

This google-services.json i put in our project root folder and another one is in platform->android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to connect anywhere.

Just download json file and put inside www folder and for iOS download plist file and put in www folder but make sure when you make build of android remove .plist file and when make build of iOS remove .json file.

When exception happen you can use below method to submit report.

```
window.cordova.plugins.firebase.crash.report("BOOM!");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer Pares Gami. You are absolutely Right.
but now i have use : **cordova-plugin-firebase-crash-report** and it's working fine

Comment: But this plugin **cordova-plugin-firebase-crash-report** are conflict with the **phonegap-plugin-push**
And cordova-plugin-firebase-crash not working as per your Answer